# How do i put the total sum of my input on top of my codes?

Tags: java, loops

First of all here is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pengulangan {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        
        int i, number, line, total;
        int even, b = 0;
        double  rat;

        System.out.print("Input number: ");
        number = sc.nextInt();
        
        even = number/2;
        System.out.print("Total sum of number from 1 to number  " + number + " is " + even + "\n");
        
        i = 2;
        line = 1;

        while (i <= number) {
            System.out.println("Even number-" + line + " is " +i);
            line = line+1;
            i = i +2;
        }
        total = ((number/2) * (even+1));
        System.out.printf("Total sum of even number from the number " + number + " = " + total + "\n");
        
        rat =  2*(total/number);
        System.out.printf("Sum of average number from the number " + number + " = " + rat + "\n");
    }
    
}
```

On this specific line on top of the second S.O.P

```
even = number/2;
```

i would like to put a loop there to find out how many Even numbers are on the input (ex- 10)

So i tried this code

```
int i = 1;

while (i <= number) {

    if (i%2 == 0)
       even = even + 1;
    else 
       odd = odd + 1; //Not going to use this..
    i++;
}
System.out.println("Total sum of even number is : ")
```

I tried putting that code in but i can't make it work, i tried it myself with only the code above and the results are exactly what im looking for but i can't put that in my first code ( the top one ), so i ended up using a sneaky way to get the even numbers.

I need help putting that total sum code to my main code

Comment: What is the issue you have when you put that code block into your main code?

Comment: Show us how your main code looks when you try to put the piece in it. And tell us what errors are you getting / what is not working.

Comment: No errors, but the output sticks with the first loop. It wont come down to the second loop after the SOP

Comment: Please explain what an SOP is?

Comment: SOP is basically System.out.print, so what i have said before is that the loop wont go down after the System.out.print

Comment: could you please make it clear on question ? do you want "total sum of input" (as mentioned in title) OR "to find out how many Even numbers are in the input" OR "Total sum of even number" ?
For someone to help you, it's required the clarity of questions and what exact code you tried.

Comment: The problem im having is to put my "total sum of even number" code on my main code shown above, as i have stated in the last statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a homework. You don't need loops or anything fancy, if you just want to get the sum of even numbers up to the number you input. Let n be the input number from your program and

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 10;
    //This is the math forumla
    int total_sum_math = (((n/2)*((n/2)+1))); 
    System.out.println("Total sum of even number is : "+total_sum_math+"");
  }
 
}
```

Reference: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3285727/sum-of-even-numbers-n